# How to send different response for AJAX request if Authentication is required in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have one application where I am using Spring Security and OAuth2 login. Everything is working. If the user is not logged in then it redirects user to login page as expected. However, this redirection is causing problem for `AJAX` request. Is there any way to send different response for `AJAX` request if user is not logged in. I tried something like this but it looks like `exceptionHandling` is not the right place to intercept such request.

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
            .authorizeExchange(authorizeExchangeSpec -> {
                authorizeExchangeSpec.anyExchange().authenticated();
            })
            .csrf(csrfSpec -> {
                csrfSpec.csrfTokenRepository(CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
            })
            .logout(logoutSpec -> {
                logoutSpec.logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository));
            })
            .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults())
            .exceptionHandling(exceptionHandlingSpec -> {
                exceptionHandlingSpec.authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> {
                    // It seems its too late here to do such check none of the header have this? Eventhough `AJAX` request triggered this.
                    if (swe.getRequest().getHeaders().containsKey("X-Requested-With")) {
                        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED));
                    }
                });
            })
            .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined **OAuth2 client** configuration: requests authorized with sessions, and response to requests with missing or invalid authorization with 302 status (redirected to login). This is fine to serve pages rendered on the server (Thymeleaf, JSF or whatever).

REST endpoints should be configured as **OAuth2 resource server**: requests authorized with access tokens, no sessions, and response to requests with missing or invalid authorization with 401 (unauthorized).

If your application serves both server-side rendered pages and REST resources, then you should define two different security filter-chains: one with client configuration and the other one with resource server configuration.

When you define more than one security filter-chain bean, those should be decorated with `@Order` to define in which order they are evaluated and all filter-chains but the last one in `@Order` should have a security matcher (something like `http.securityMatcher("/api/**")` for a resource server filter chain) to restrict it to the resources it should secure and give a chance to those with higher order to process the request (evaluated next if the security matcher didn't match).

More details in [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) (one is dedicated to apps serving both a REST API and a Thymeleaf client).